# "Notice: Undefined offset: 0" when adding first item to array

Tags: php

When I try to add a first item it gives "Notice: Undefined offset: 0" as an error because of the fact that the array is empty, how can I let the title be "Test" the first time I add an item? The array also needs to be emptied sometimes so it should still work after that

```
$result = $query->getResult();

    if(($result[0]->getId())>0){
        $title = "Test" . ($result[0]->getId() + 1);
    }

    else{
        $title = "Test";
    }
```

Comment: Use `count($result) > 0` to test if the array has values. You might also want an `isset` and / or `is_array`, but it really depends.

Comment: Like @JonStirling said, user `count` or `ìsset` or `!empty()` to check if the array contains data before trying to access the first element of the array (0)

Comment: do like this:- `$result = $query->getResult();
if(count($result)>0){
 if($result[0]->getId() > 0){
  $title = "Test" . ($result[0]->getId() + 1);
 }else{
  $title = "Test";
 }
}`